# A date-time is coming from the database, I want to extract it from the current date-time and refresh it for 1 min. How can I do this?

Tags: javascript, react-native, datetime, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-flatlist

```
    return(
        <View style={{ flex:1, marginTop:10}}>   
             
            <FlatList
            style={{height:'100%'}}
            data={users}
            numColumns={1}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
            
            <Pressable
                style={styles.container} >
                  <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                     <View style={styles.box}>

                     <Text style={styles.itemFood}>{item.food_name}</Text>
                     <Text style={styles.itemRestaurant}>{item.restaurant}</Text>
                     <Text style={styles.itemPrice}>{item.price}</Text>
                     <Text style={styles.itemPiece}>{item.piece}</Text>
                     <Text style={styles.itemNew}>{item.new_price}</Text>

                    <Image style={styles.itemİmg} 
                    source={{ uri: item.img }}  />
                    
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Pressable>
     )}
             />   
        </View>
   )
}
```

I'm getting the data from the Firestore Database. I also use a Flatlist. In my mobile application, I want to apply discounts on some products in a certain time zone ( time range ).  How can I add a counter (countdown) to this block of code using the Firestore database?